# Get current lat long android

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to get the Location object on Button press.
I know the LocationListener callbacks, however they execute only after a particular time or distance. I want to get Location instantaneously. Are there any methods to do so.

Comment: take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Comment: androidhive is a bad tutorial source ... fx in this tutorial GPSTracker class extends Service ... what for? and why it is "started" using `new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);`? good tutorials are on (drums! ... more drums!) http://d.android.com (training section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are welcome to call `getLastKnownLocation()` on `LocationManager` to retrieve the last known location for your requested location provider. However:

- that location may be old
- that location may be `null`

Hence, your code will need to be able to cope with both of those scenarios.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class GPSHelper {

    private Context context;
    // flag for GPS Status
    private boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // flag for network status
    private boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location location;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public GPSHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        locationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }   public void getMyLocation() {
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

        Location l = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < providers.size(); i++) {
            l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(providers.get(i));
            if (l != null)
                break;
        }
        if (l != null) {
            latitude = l.getLatitude();
            longitude = l.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    public boolean isGPSenabled() {
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        return (isGPSEnabled || isNetworkEnabled);
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `LocationManager` class:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if (location != null) {
    latitude=location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
    Log.d("old","lat :  "+latitude);
    Log.d("old","long :  "+longitude);
    this.onLocationChanged(location);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what my manager is saying is that if Google Maps can show location instantaneously, then it should be possible.

Comment: Google map uses these code inside it, moreover its "Google Maps"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation

If your location is enabled, you need just 3 lines of code:

```
SimpleLocation location = new SimpleLocation(this); //or context instead of this
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can get the last known location using FusedLocationProviderClient**

There are very simple steps to get current latitude, longitude, altitude & bearing

1. Update or install Google Play services to the current latest version in your SDK Manager.

[image: SDK manager's screen-shot in Android studio]

2. Add Location permission into your project's manifest.

[image]

3. Add this line into your Activity/Fragment:

(i) **Code For Kotlin**

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "latitude:" + location?.latitude)
                    Log.d(TAG, "longitude:" + location?.longitude)
                    Log.d(TAG, "altitude:" + location?.altitude)
                    Log.d(TAG, "bearing:" + location?.bearing)
                }
```

**(ii) Code for JAVA**

```
 private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
 fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
        .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                     Log.d(TAG,location.getLatitude) 
                     Log.d(TAG,location.getLongitude) 
                }
            }
        });
```

That's it. Run your code and you can check your current location in Logcat. Don't forget to **accept location permission** from your emulator or Android phone.

You can not get proper altitude and bearing using FusedLocationProviderClient.

Happy Coding :)