# Get current location (lat,long) in android google map when app start

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-gps

**FYI:** *I've searched for an appropriate answer but couldn't find one. Most of them are old and used deprecated methods.*

What I need is, when the app start it will display google map with marker at the current position. I can set marker using latitude and longitude. But, I couldn't find any way of getting current lat-long using **GPS**.

Could you please help me to get the current lat-long using GPS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code that I am using to get my current Lat-Lng value:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
double lat = location.getLatitude();
double lng = location.getLongitude();
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: returns null for me

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer on a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52209682/9375838

Use this:
https://github.com/delight-im/Android-SimpleLocation

If your location is enabled, you need just 3 lines of code:

```
SimpleLocation location = new SimpleLocation(this); //or context instead of this
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [GPS Tracker](https://github.com/ece1778github/Experience/blob/master/Application%20Source%20Code/com/example/ece1778project/GPSTracker.java) that is available on github. Functions `getLongitude()` and `getLatitude()` will return the current location.

Comment: Do NOT use this class.  Its badly, badly broken.  We get questions here about why it doesn't return the right results all the time.  I have an explanation of how its broken at http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/

Comment: It works for me but I will take into consideration your post.

Comment: It works a percentage of the time. But it's flawed code that should not be suggested to anyone else